# Rails 4: How do I properly link_to edit_path on index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I am new to rails and stuck with a probably easy to answer question. I have a controller and model (Tools / Tool) and I linked the edit_path from the show page of the Tool. But how can I also link it from my index and search page?

**Here is the relevant code:**
*/app/controllers/tools_controller.rb*

```
class ToolsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_tool, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @tools = Tool.where(user_id: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
        @user = current_user
    end

    def search
        @tools = Tool.all
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @tool = current_user.tools.build
    end

    def create
        @tool = current_user.tools.build(tool_params)

        if @tool.save
            redirect_to tools_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @tool.update(tool_params)
            redirect_to tools_path
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @tool.destroy
        redirect_to tools_path
    end

    private

    def find_tool
        @tool = Tool.find(params[:id])
    end

    def tool_params
        params.require(:tool).permit(:title, :subtitle, :url)
    end
end
```

*/app/views/tools/show.html.haml*

```
%h1= @tool.title

= link_to "Back", :back
= link_to @tool.user.try(:username), '/users/'+@tool.user_id.to_s

= link_to "Edit", edit_tool_path(@tool)
= link_to "Delete", tool_path(@tool), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
enter code here
```

*/app/views/tools/index.html.haml*

```
%h2 My Tools
- @tools.each do |tool|
    %h2= link_to tool.title, tool
    %p= tool.subtitle
    %p= link_to "Edit", edit_path
    %p= time_ago_in_words(tool.created_at)



-if @user.use_gravatar?
    = image_tag gravatar_for @user
- else
    = image_tag @user.avatar_filename.url

%h1= @user.username

= link_to "Edit", edit_user_registration_path
```

*/app/views/tools/search.html.haml*

```
- @tools.each do |tool|
    %h2= link_to tool.title, tool
    %p= tool.subtitle
    %p= link_to tool.user.try(:username), '/users/'+tool.user_id.to_s
    %p= link_to "Edit", edit_path
    %p= time_ago_in_words(tool.created_at)
```

I hope the provided data is enough, if not please tell me. I'm grateful for all Your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looping through the `@tools` using the `tool` variable, you can do something like this.

```
= link_to 'Edit', edit_tool_path(tool)
```

This is similar to how you linked the `tool`'s `title` to the `show` action from index view using

`= link_to tool.title, tool`

Your index view should look something like

```
- @tools.each do |tool|
  %h2= link_to tool.title, tool
  %p= tool.subtitle
  %p= link_to "Edit", edit_tool_path(tool)
  %p= time_ago_in_words(tool.created_at)
```

Do the same for the `search` view.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @J.Hübotter Glad that it helped!